# How can I prove that the first line of a singular Toeplitz matrix is linearly dependant of the others?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, signal-processing, toeplitz-matrices

Here is a Toeplitz matrix of the form:

\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{0} &   a_1    & a_2 &\cdots&a_n\\
a_{-1} &   a_0    & a_1 &\cdots&a_{n-1}&\\
a_{-2} &   a_{-1} & a_0&\cdots&a_{n-2}\\
\vdots &   \vdots & \vdots &\ddots&\vdots\\
a_{-n} & a_{-n+1} & a_{-n+2}&\cdots&a_0
\end{pmatrix}

We assume that the matrix $A \geq 0$, which means that $(AX, X) \geq 0$ $\forall X \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. We also assume that the determinant of this matrix is $0$.

I know that the $\det = 0$ constraint the values of the elements down the diagonal like in a $2 \times 2$ matrix, the value of the element down the main diagonal should be the product of the element on the main diagonal divided by the other element, i.e $a_{2,1} = (a_{1,1}\times a_{2,2}) \div a_{1,2} $

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: You need to clarify whether $A$ is self-adjoint (as implied by $A\ge0$) or not (as implied by using $a_{-1}$).

Comment: @Chrystomath It seems to be self-adjoint

Comment: But what would happen in both case ??

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is not invertible ($\det A=0$) then there must be a vector $x$ such that $x^TA=0$ (this follows since $A^T$ is also singular). Expanding out $$0=x^TA=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf{a}_i$$ where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the $i$th row of $A$; so if $x_1\ne0$ then $\mathbf{a}_1$ can be written as a linear combination of the rest of the rows.

However this is not always possible. For example, $\begin{pmatrix}4&8&5\\2&4&8\\1&2&4\end{pmatrix}$ is of the given form and singular, yet the first row cannot be written as a linear combination of the other rows.

Comment: And why is it the case in by example this kind of situation ?

Comment: @NahumMaurice Look at the last two rows.

Comment: Your matrix isn't self-adjoint.

Comment: @Ruy Ik, that's why I asked for clarification, in the comments, because the question seems to assume $a_{-1}\ne a_1$. It does satisfy $(Ax,x)\ge0$ though.

Comment: I see!  It is certainly very confusing to say "$A \geq 0$, *which means that* $(AX, X) \geq 0$", since these things are only equivalent over the complexes!

Comment: @Ruy can you refer me to some literature that shows up why these things are only equivalent over the complexes?

Comment: For the complex case you could consult Proposition (2.4.6) in the first volume of Kadison and Ringrose.  A  counter-example in the real case is the matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr -1 & 0}$.